# SQl Live: Displaying Min value of column, plus corresponding value in same table, plus related value in second table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, DEPT and EMP. EMP has a deptno column that corresponds to the deptno column in DEPT. I need to display the earliest (min) hiredate (another column in EMP) of each department in DEPT, the dname( department name), and the name of the employee(ename)

Here is the code I have so far, but I'm not sure how to modify it to also display the corresponding name of the employee.

```
SELECT dname, MIN(hiredate) AS "Most Senior"

FROM dept, emp  
WHERE dept.deptno = emp.deptno  
GROUP BY dname
```

**Edit** here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dept(   
  deptno     number(2,0),   
  dname      varchar2(14),   
  loc        varchar2(13),   
  CONSTRAINT pk_dept PRIMARY KEY (deptno)   
);

CREATE TABLE emp(

  empno    number(4,0),   
  ename    varchar2(10),   
  job      varchar2(9),   
  mgr      number(4,0),   
  hiredate date,   
  sal      number(7,2),   
  comm     number(7,2),   
  deptno   number(2,0),   
  CONSTRAINT pk_emp PRIMARY KEY (empno),   
  CONSTRAINT fk_deptno FOREIGN KEY (deptno) REFERENCES dept (deptno)   
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add one more condition comparing the hiredate as well. If you can give table structure and some sample data would be more helpful to answer.

```
SELECT 
  dname,
  e.ename,
  min(e.hiredate) as hire_date 
FROM 
  dept as d, emp e 
where 
  d.deptno = e.deptno 
group by 
  d.deptno
having
  e.hiredate = hire_date
```

Comment: I'm having a problem with the syntax, this gives me an error saying the command is not properly ended

Comment: I have made typo in previous query. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`, if your DBMS supports it.

```
SELECT x.hiredate,
       x.dname,
       x.ename
       FROM (SELECT e.hiredate,
                    d.dname,
                    e.ename,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY d.deptno
                                       ORDER BY e.hiredate) rn
                    FROM dept d
                         INNER JOIN emp e
                                    ON e.deptno = d.deptno) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

I also recommend to use the explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the swift answer
I'm brand new to SQL and am not overly familiar with how to use row_number() so I'm not sure what all of the syntax here means. What is the x.hiredate,  x.dname, x.ename doing exactly?

Comment: @GoldPonyBoy: The `x` is just an alias for the subquery. So with `x.<column name>` I just refer to a column from the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select d.dname, d.*
from dept d join
     emp e
     on d.deptno = e.deptno
where e.hiredate = (select min(e2.hiredate) from emp e2 where e2.deptno = e.deptno);
```

You can also solve this problem using `row_number()` or `rank()`.  In many databases, the correlated subquery often has better performance, particularly with an index on `e(deptno, hiredate)`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select not just the min(hire_date) but also the associated employee you will need to use some method of ranking employees by their hire_date within the department. Easiest way to do this is using a row_number function. Using your example code:

`select dept.dname
, emp.hiredate as "most_senior" 
, emp.ename as "senior_employee"
from dept 
join 
(select * 
, row_number(PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY hiredate) as rn
from emp
) emp
on dept.deptno = emp.deptno
and emp.rn = 1
;`

Comment: This gives me an error saying a "FROM keyword not found where expected" I apologize if I'm missing something syntax wise, I haven't used the row_number() before

Comment: edited my code to be more explicit, that should solve the issue.